# How to constraint an object's keys but infer values as const?

Tags: typescript

Given this object, is there a way to infer its values as `const` while ensuring the keys are contained in the `Field` union?

```
type Field = 'name' | 'isHappy';

const fieldTypes: { [field in Field]: string } = {
  name: 'text',
  isHappy: 'checkbox',
};
```

My goal is so that `fieldTypes` has the type:

```
{
  name: 'text';
  isHappy: 'checkbox';
}
```

instead of

```
{
  name: string;
  isHappy: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not just a variable declaration. Variable types are either inferred from the value assigned or are specified by a type annotation, there is no middle ground.

You can instead use a function, which can have a type both inferred and constrained:

```
type Field = 'name' | 'isHappy';

function createFields<T extends Record<Field, V>, V extends string>(o: T) {
  return o;
}

const fieldTypes = createFields({
  name: 'text',
  isHappy: 'checkbox',
})

// Typed as: 
// const fieldTypes: {
//     name: "text";
//     isHappy: "checkbox";
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEygXigcgHYEMC2EmUAPlnAM4ASuYYImA3AFDMBmArtgMbBwD22KNwBOEXMAjwkyCgB4AKlAgAPSdllQAShG78RyOdJQAaKADUAfGfPK1EDRSgVgIuNgDmlgBT8AXFAKAJRQAN7MUFBiwBwiQvwsAL6setguUGwIKArgEE4YouKSxrLe4ZF4hAGYkmqYJhFQlDR0INXcABa6ANYARvwq9cyJQawA9GOBuai4FAHME8KC6ZkyOZBzYQuTkRUEEAEARLXAhyyLu03UtPRHnT39KmfbUIlAA)

Comment: I think `V extends string` is redundant.

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh The request was to maintain string literal types. You can do that only if you introduce a type parameter, any value assigned to a type parameter constrained to one of the types that can produce literal types will not be widened. Without the `V` we just get `string` for property types.